# TestNG 7.0.1 deprecated method for getRetryAnalyzer()

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

The following method **getRetryAnalyzer** are deprecated in testng 7.0.1. Here is my code:

```
public ITestAnnotation annotations;

@Override
public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
    annotations =annotation;
    if(null == annotation.getRetryAnalyzer()) {
        annotation.setRetryAnalyzer(Retry.class);
    }
}

@Override
public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
}

@Override
public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
    ((Retry) annotations.getRetryAnalyzer()).reset();
    
}

@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    ((Retry) annotations.getRetryAnalyzer()).reset();
}
```

I tried to replace it with **getRetryAnalyzerClass()** but it was not working. Can anyone tell me how I can fix this deprecated method?

Answer (score 0):

This method stands deprecated as of TestNG 7.0.0. Please use `{ITestAnnotation.getRetryAnalyzerClass()}` instead.

Check the following [link](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.testng/testng/7.0.0-beta3/org/testng/ITestNGMethod.html#getRetryAnalyzer--)

the code will be as following:

```
Class<? extends IRetryAnalyzer> retry = testannotation.getRetryAnalyzerClass();
```